# Trouble Adding Basic Lock Screen in Lubuntu 14

Tags: lubuntu, shutdown, lock-screen

Alright, I'm running the latest version of Lubuntu on my system, Lubuntu 14, and some strange things have been happening when trying to set up a lock screen.

Since I use a laptop, all I want to do is make it so that the system asks for a password if I 1.) Hit the windows key + L, 2.) manually lock the screen, or 3.) fold the laptop. I've tried doing this all through the light locker settings in the preferences category.

However, whenever I set the option, other things happen.

First, while I was successful in being able to lock my screen through the log-out prompt, after I get done doing the other tasks the computer display won't turn back on. The power button is still glowing, but I have to do a forced shut-down since no keyboard input affects anything.

Secondly, in response to that, I went back to light locker settings and disabled the shut-off display option, but then when I tried locking the screen again, the computer shut off on its own.

So what's going on here? Again, my only desires are a password prompt under the conditions listed above.

NOTE: I've discovered that if I close the lid for a prolonged time, it'll then go into the lock screen as I desire. I don't know why, though. The time it takes seems arbitrary, for if I leave the lid down for a few seconds the lock-screen won't activate. It's most desirable for me to be able to do it immediately on command.

Comment: How are you setting the options?  Are you using the Xfce Power Manager?

Comment: I set it via Light Locker Settings in Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your options under the Xfce Power Manager.  You can reach it from the Main Menu->Preferences->Power Manager  or right clicking the little battery icon on the LXPanel and choosing Preferences.

Comment: I looked, but apparently all the settings match what I want. For instance, it says that it'll lock the screen if I set the laptop lid down. However, I tried that, and it won't do so unless an unspecified amount of time passes; if I close the lid and lift it after 5 secs or so, the display comes back on without the lock screen.